# How to create a shorthand for 'this.getAttribute'

Tags: javascript

Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm not sure if shorthand is the correct word. But, it's the closest I can come up with:

For example:
`this.getAttribute`

I am using this a lot throughout one of my scripts, over 20 items.

Is it possible to just reference it like:

`getA`

or something? Instead of typing this.getAttribute over and over again?  I know it seems likes a first world problem, but I am very OCD about my code and like to be minimal but still sustain readability. getA to reference this.getAttribute still makes a alot of sense (to me anyway), and in essence, shorter code. Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sure, just replace it with a function that's called like `attr(this, what)` etc

Comment: what about `var getA = this.getAttribute` ?

Comment: But this is not really somerhing to be OCD about, you should be more concerned with writing readable and nicely formatted code, and then just minify it for production

Comment: @Jfk That won't work, because it doesn't use the current value of `this` when you call it.

Comment: You can even extend `Element` with `Element.prototype.getA = Element.prototype.getAttribute` but I strongly advise against it.

Comment: Whatever you do, you won't be able to get around having to use `this` when you call it. E.g. `this.getA(...)` or `getA(this, ...)`

Comment: @Barmar it depends if the OP is getting the attribute of the same element over an over again, but the question is not clear about it.

Comment: If that's what he wants, he'd need to do something like `getA = Element.prototype.getAttribute.bind(this);`

Comment: @Barmar you are correct. At times you write something different of what you are thinking, mostly when writing quickly

Comment: We forgot `with`. Highly discouraged, but also an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a function like this:

```
function getA(element, attr) {
    return element.getAttribute(attr);
}
```

And then, instead of `this.getAttribute(attr)`, use `getA(this, attr)`.

However, if you want to use it to get several attributes of the same element, and you want to avoid avoid passing `this` each time, you can use

```
var getA = this.getAttribute.bind(this);
```

And then, instead of `this.getAttribute(attr)`, use `getA(attr)`.

Comment: Hey Oriol,

I'm getting:  Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Do I need to always pass `this`? Because if I need to always pass this to the function, this it not even worth the amount of code shorthanded. But I am trying the getA(attr) method you have explained, but getting that error. hmmm

Comment: @NiCkNewman That means `this.getAttribute` is undefined. Are you sure `this` is an `Element`? For example, you can use `var getA = document.body.getAttribute.bind(document.body); getA('foo'); getA('bar')`

Comment: Well, in my case (this) is getting a data-attribute element, so yea?

I'm using it as `getA('data-identify')`  and data-identify is an attribute inside my this element.  I think I'm a bit lost, one sec.

Comment: Okay. I used `getA = document.body.getAttribute.bind(document.body); `, and then using getA('attributehere') and it's not erroring out, but returning 'NULL'. Weird.. What the..

Comment: @NiCkNewman `Null` returning means that the attribute doesn't exist on that element.

Comment: @NiCkNewman First run `document.body.setAttribute('attributehere', 'foobar')`, and then `getA('attributehere')` will return `'foobar'`.

Comment: @Oriol, that won't work though because my `this` is dynamic and is based upon elements inside a function? For example:

`iitems = qsa('.itemdrag'); 
for(i=0; i < iitems.length; i++){
iitems[i].onclick=function(){
console.log( getA('data-identify')
}`

qsa is returning document.querySelectorAll.  And, data-identify is an attribute for each .itemdrag element, so with that said (maybe I should have included this in my question LOL, sorry!).  I will always need to call `this` then, right?

Comment: @Oriol, my bad. I should of thought out my question more, what an absolute joke this was. I'm using this inside a function, so ofcourse it will be need to be passed, because it is dynamic. I marked yours as the best answer, and apologizes for putting you through this cesspool of a question. Thanks everyone for your help. (Since this has to be called, shorthanding this is a dumb idea, and not really saving any code now that I think about it :D) Sometimes it's best for me to explain my question out in a post, to help me better understand my own code.. Weird, I know ha.

Comment: @NiCkNewman Yes. The `getA` way which doesn't need `this` in only useful if you want to get lots of attributes of the same element. Otherwise, if `this` varies, you must pass it.

Answer (score 2):

if you call assign a method of an object to a var and call it by that, it the value of `this` inside the method will be the global context, as the function context is bound to where it got called from, so you can't do that.

However, you can use the built in Function method `bind` to preserve the context, but it's a rather expensive operation just to alias your method.

```
var getA = this.getAttribute.bind(this);
getA("yourAttribute");
```

or use `call` to enforce the context when you call it

```
var getA = this.getAttribute;
getA.call(this,"yourAttribute");
```

but both are not really great and in most cases all you need to do is to keep the actual return value in a var and reuse that, without invoking the getter at all. The getter is verbose because that's a good way to make an expensive method look expensive, and discourage people from calling it 20 times in a row in the first place. They usually **should only be called when you expect a different result**.

```
var a = this.getAttribute("yourAttribute");
```

When you say you call it 20 times in 20 different places I'm relatively sure those are not 20 places that expect the value to be different, especially when they are inside the same function scope.

If you are dealing with custom `data-*` attributes you can also just directly retrieve it from the `.data` property on your element, it's a map of all your data-attributes which is the ideal scenario.

```
<element data-your-attribute="yourData"></element>

var a = this.data.yourAttribute; //automatically updated and name converted from dash to camelCase
```

(all examples assume `this` refers to you element, and your function is a method of your element)

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up:

@Adeneo says:

```
 function getA(element, attr)
 {
     return element.getAttribute(attr);
 }
```

I said:

```
 Element.prototype.getA = Element.prototype.getAttribute
```

Which can be used as:

```
 var attr = getA(document.getElementById("test"), "attr"); //Adeneo
 var attr = document.getElementById("test").getA("attr"); //Mouser
```

I strongly advise against extending the Element object.

jQuery does the following:

They have their master function object `$`. That function has a method called `attr`. So the master function object finds an element on the page to which you can call the method `attr`.

```
$("element").attr("attr");
```

To reproduce:

```
var masterFunction = function(selector)
{
    this.result = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}

var selectElement = function(selector)
{
    return new masterFunction(selector);
}

masterFunction.prototype.attr = function(attr)
{
    var returnArray = [];
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.result, function(element){
        if (element.hasAttribute(attr))
        {
            returnArray.push(element.getAttribute(attr))
        }
    });
    return returnArray;
}
```

Please remember that this, like jQuery returns an array containing the results.

Comment: Hey Mouser,

If I use `Element.prototype.getA = Element.prototype.getAttribute`, I get:

`getA is not defined`

Comment: @NiCkNewman, works fine here. You need to define this on the top of your scrip block. It sets a new function to all HTML elements on the page. You call it by doing `element.getA()`. For example: `document.getElementById("element").getA("attr")`

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad. I forgot to include element.getA(). I just used getA.  Now looking back, my question is kind of dumb. Because this is not really saving code now since I need to pass (this/element) each time anyway. I was just thinking of doing something like 

`getA = this.getAttribute;`

Then, just using this below my function lol, but I wish JS was that easy.  I shot myself in the foot with this question, appreciate your help.

Comment: It's actually not a bad question, the answers here provide a lot of learning experience. Like @Adeneo said. Don't worry about writing minimalistic code. Just write readable and nicely formatted code. You can obfuscate it when going to production.

Comment: Yep, now looking back... I am using `this` inside a function, so It will always have to be passed. Wow, embarrassing now that I posted my code. Oh well.